# SQL - ORDER BY with UNIONed hardcoded values?

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-order-by, union

Here is a bit of pseudocode to explain what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT
'"'|| 'ID' ||'"' ||','||
'"'|| 'FIRST_NAME' ||'"' ||','||
'"'|| 'LAST_NAME' ||'"'
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT   
'"'|| ID ||'"' ||','||
'"'|| FIRST_NAME ||'"' ||','||
'"'|| LAST_NAME || ' " '
FROM TEMP_TABLE;
```

I'm creating a CSV file and I have to hardcode my column names so that when the user imports the CSV file into Excel, the columns and data will display properly.

How do I ensure that the first half of the query - the column names - appears first in this CSV file? An ORDER BY clause kicks back an error, presumably because the first half of the query doesn’t define column names, so there is nothing to be ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inline view for your real query, and add a dummy column to each branch; then use that for the ordering, but only select your real column. e..g:

```
SELECT csv
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS order_col,
  '"'|| 'ID' ||'"' ||','||
  '"'|| 'FIRST_NAME' ||'"' ||','||
  '"'|| 'LAST_NAME' ||'"' AS csv
  FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2, 
  '"'|| ID ||'"' ||','||
  '"'|| FIRST_NAME ||'"' ||','||
  '"'|| LAST_NAME || ' " '
  FROM TEMP_TABLE
)
ORDER BY order_col, csv;
```

Or you could look for the fixed values in a case expression, which also requires an inline view, and is more repetitive:

```
SELECT csv
FROM (
  SELECT
  '"'|| 'ID' ||'"' ||','||
  '"'|| 'FIRST_NAME' ||'"' ||','||
  '"'|| 'LAST_NAME' ||'"' AS csv
  FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT   
  '"'|| ID ||'"' ||','||
  '"'|| FIRST_NAME ||'"' ||','||
  '"'|| LAST_NAME || ' " '
  FROM TEMP_TABLE
)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN csv = '"ID","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME"' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, csv;
```

---

Not relevant, but your first branch doesn't need all that concatenation...

```
...
  SELECT 1 AS order_col,
  '"ID","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME"' AS csv
  FROM DUAL
...
```

but I guess it makes maintenance easier as you can see when the headings and columns don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You could hardcode a value and use it to sort.

```
SELECT Col
FROM (
SELECT
'"'|| 'ID' ||'"' ||','||
'"'|| 'FIRST_NAME' ||'"' ||','||
'"'|| 'LAST_NAME' ||'"' AS Col,
1 AS Sort
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT   
'"'|| ID ||'"' ||','||
'"'|| FIRST_NAME ||'"' ||','||
'"'|| LAST_NAME || ' " ',
2
FROM TEMP_TABLE) Table1
ORDER BY Sort ASC
```